# I cannot connect another ec2 instance from my currently running ec2 instance both having the same key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-20-1-190 ~]$ ssh -i "mykeypair.pem" ec2-user@172.20.4.46
```

That's the command I was trying to run to access another ec2 instance from my current ec2 instance but it says

> Warning: Identity file mykeypair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
>
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You currently have a file `mykeypair.pem` on your laptop/desktop computer that you are using to connect to the first EC2 instance. You would need to copy that file to the first EC2 instance if you want to use it to connect to another instance from there.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to copy mykeypair.pem or can proxy through first host to 2nd using below command

```
ssh -i  mykeypair.pem ec2-user@172.20.4.46 -o "proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p -i mykeypair.pem ec2-user@172.20.1.190"
```